# Internet Explorer , Jquery $.post

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, post

```
$.post("example.php",function(data){
    alert(data); // result: undefined
})
```

**Example.php**

```
hello ie are you ok?
```

Why is `alert(data)` undefined in IE? It works in other browsers.

Comment: not enough information to say. Try the done/fail tests explained on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post in the section on "The jqXHR Object"

Comment: Maybe because of missing ";" in the end of .post({...}) ? IE is stupid, you know, a missing semi-colon is enough to break it LOL